# How to add raw HTML / custom elements on amp-story-consent

Tags: html, ampscript, amp-story

I am trying to integrate "amp-consent" in my project where I want to keep an option to add multiple HTML elements like list, table, hyperlink but I don't see how to do it in documentation.
All I see is example which accepts 3 inputs in script under "amp-story-consent" and all of them accept string values alone. There is no way to add even a paragraph or hyperlink in the description.
Any ideas?